# Why does $\frac{dx}{\cos x}$ cancel out in this integration by substitution

Tags: integration, substitution

I just learnt about integration by substitution and do not understand why parts of the integration cancel out.

For example

$$\int\cos x\sqrt{1+\sin x} dx$$

where $u = 1+\sin x$. Therefore
we integrate
$$\int(u-1)u^3 du$$

as
$$\begin{split}
u &= 1+\sin x\\
\sin x &= u-1\\
dx&= \frac{du}{\cos x}\\
\end{split}$$

Why is it that when we put this together as follows

$$\int (\cos x)(u-1)u^3 \frac{du}{\cos x}$$

the $\cos x$ and $\frac{du}{\cos x}$ cancel out.

What does $\frac{du}{\cos x}$ actually mean, that may help me understand?

We are not multiplying the integral are we $(\int (\cos x)(u-1)u^3\frac{du}{\cos x})$ - so that is why is cancels out.

Comment: The justification lies in working backwards. Start with $\int (u-1)u^{3}du$ and check that this becomes the original integral when $u=1+\sin x$.

Comment: To integrate $\int cos(x)(1+ sin(x))^{1/2} dx$ let u= 1+ sin(x) so du= cos(x) dx.  Do NOT think "$dx= \frac{du}{cos(x)}$" but rather that the integral can be written $\int (1+ sin(x))^{1/2} (cos(x)dx)= \int u^{1/2}du[/math].

Comment: If $u=1+\sin x$, how does the $(u-1)u^3$ come from $\int \cos x \sqrt{1+\sin x}\ dx$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When considering this integral, you have the correct $u$ for the substitution; however, you are attempting a u-sub-back-sub, which isn't a technique required for this problem.

If you let $u=1+\sin(x)$, then you can think of the derivative as $\displaystyle \frac{du}{dx}=\cos(x)$, which we can, in turn, write as $du=\cos(x)dx$. This is technically an abuse of the differential notation; however, it is an excellent visual and tracks.

So, with that choice of $u$, you can rewrite the integral as

$$ \int\sqrt{1+\sin(x)} \cos(x)dx, \text{ move the cosine to the end by commutativity of multiplication.}$$

$$ \stackrel{u-sub}{=}\int\sqrt{u}\,du, \text{the cos(x) dx term becomes du entirely.} $$

From there, the standard power rule for integration is applied, and substituting your original $u$ back into the resulting antiderivative gives the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

There are two schools of thought on differentials. One is that they only exist *within* derivatives.  That is, $du$ is a somewhat non-sensical term on its own, but $\frac{du}{dx}$ is fine. The other is that differentials represent actual, distinct numbers/concepts on their own, and thus are more-or-less "free-living".  You can read $du$ as "an infinitely small change in the variable $u$ coordinated in size with other infinitely small changes to other variables in the equation."  For a more rigorous approach, see Fite's "[Total and Partial Differentials...](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.07958)".  With this approach, derivatives are just ratios of differentials (note that this has additional implications when dealing with partial differentials or higher-order differentials, for which I would refer you to the paper).

As a free-living entity, $du$ can be put into ratio with anything, though.  So, $\frac{du}{\cos(x)}$ is literally just the ratio given, just like any other ratio.  Therefore, the $\cos(x)$'s can cancel just like for any other fraction.

All that being said, I think that @ethansmith's approach was more straightforward, but even there I would say that writing $du = \cos(x)\,dx$ isn't an abuse of notation (if you take the view as I do that $du$ can be a free-living entity).