# Why is $\int u\frac{dv}{dx} \, dx = \int u\ dv $? (Change of Variable while deriving Integration by Parts)

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, differential, change-of-variable

I have been learning the integration by parts formula.

$$\int u\ \mathrm dv = uv \ - \ \int v\ \mathrm du $$

I understand how the formula is derived when we keep everything in terms of $x$ (with $f(x)$ and $g'(x)$, etc.), but when we derive it using $u$ and $v$, we end up doing this at one point:
$$\int u\frac{dv}{dx} \, \mathrm dx = \int u\ \mathrm dv $$
I don't quite understand how we go from the left hand to the right hand. Can someone help me with the intuition/reason we cancel out the $\mathrm dx$?

I have been taught to treat $\mathrm dy/\mathrm dx$, $\mathrm dv/\mathrm dx$, the $\mathrm dx$ in an integral, etc. as symbols and operators, not different parts of some fraction. Why are we cancelling the $\mathrm dx$ out, or why does it appear that way?

Comment: You should quote the entire integration by parts formula. $\int u dv = uv - \int v du.$

Comment: This is more of a question of change of variables no?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I am new to a some of the terminology...

Comment: It is easiest to not write in irrelevant letters. In this case, integration by parts is written $\int f’g=fg-\int fg’$

Comment: But what about the dx?

Comment: Write $\int f’g=fg-\int fg’$ as $$\int\frac{df}{dx}g\,dx=fg-\int f\frac{dg}{dx}\,dx$$ and you get $\int g\,df=fg-\int f\,dg\,.$

Comment: I understand how it appears to cancel out the dx's, but those aren't really fractions, right? They're the derivative of a function in terms of x. How can you cancel out the bottom of what I've been taught is a symbolic representation? Or why does it appear that way?

Comment: O yeah that fraction question again. You must have heard of the change of variables formula for integrals. Or about the chain rule perhaps?

Comment: Those who have studied advanced calculus a.k.a. Calculus of variations often say $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is not a fraction.  However, in practice we can sometimes or often treat it as a fraction and "cancel out"  $\frac{dy}{dx} \cdot dx=dy$  I never took that particular advanced calculus course.  When we're allowed to cancel and when we cannot cancel seems primarily to depend on who I'm talking to.

Comment: In Differential Equations, specifically separation of variables we frequently multiply both sides by $dx$ and cancel $y' dx = \frac{dy}{dx} \cdot dx = dy$  Even after 30 years of doing and teaching Calculus I don't see the requirement behind $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is not a fraction.

Comment: Ethan Smith explains it better "This is technically an abuse of the differential notation; however, it is an excellent visual and tracks."  
in a related question.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4650537/why-does-fracdx-cos-x-cancel-out-in-this-integration-by-substitution?rq=1

Comment: I think that link leads to a good answer. I will do some more looking into it. Thank you!

Comment: It might be more clear to just write the integration by parts formula as $\int u v’ \, dx = - \int u’ v \, dx + uv$.

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but I want to intuitively know why it can then be simplified from ∫uv′dx to ∫udv. I can use the rule to solve problems and everything, I just don't understand why it is written in this way...

Comment: I would say that 99% of the time it is written this way to make it easier to remember for calculus students. As for why this can be done, it is essentially changing variables via a substitution inside each integral. There is a decent explainer and picture for this process on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Visualization